# In wordpress is there any plugin/shortcode to show current post permalink on the frontend?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to create a copy to clipboard option for the post url below each post in wordpress. Exactly like the picture example below:

[image: Image of what functionality is required, mainly a option to copy the post url in post page]
I have tried to use copy to clipboard plugin, but the problem is how to display url of the post dynamically in the page. If I display it with shortcode and then try to use 'copy to clipboard' plugin shortcode, it becomes like this: [copy][post_url][/copy], which is combination of 2 shortcodes and it don't work.
Is there any other suitable plugin/shortcode? How can this be achieved without coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution and putting it here for use of others if needed. I could not find a plugin suitable for showing the post url and copying it to the clipboard. Though there are many plugins to copy to clipboard and many plugins to show/change post url, but it was not possible to combine shortcodes of 2 plugins and make it work. So I had to write a code for the task with php, js. Here is the code below:

```
<div class="after-post">
<!-- The text field -->
<input type="text" value="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" id="fgifcopyurl">

<!-- The button used to copy the text -->
<button id="fgifcpbtn" onclick="fgifcopyurl()">Copy</button> 
</div>

<script>
function fgifcopyurl() {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("fgifcopyurl");
  var fgifcpbtn=document.getElementById("fgifcpbtn");

  // Select the text field
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

   // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  // Change the button text

document.querySelector("#fgifcpbtn").innerHTML = 'Copied!';

} 

</script>
```

The code is placed in site with wp code plugin